# Формирование сводной таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть база данных со списком товаров и списком фирм необходимо сформировать таблицу вида:

```
|наименование|Альфа|Бета|Гамма|  
|карандаш    |     |    |  1  |  
|ручка       |  2  |  3 |     |  
|ластик      |     |  4 |     |  
|ножницы     |     |    |  5  |
```

т.е. количество товара с разбивкой по фирмам в одной таблице.

Пока что сделал запрос сгруппированный и отсортированный по наименованию и фирме. Мыслей хватает только на то, чтобы последовательно формировать столбцы массива по фирмам. Есть ли альтернативный способ?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста используемую СУБД. B Microsoft SQL Server есть [**PIVOT**](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: использую phpmyadmin база mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема решена. если кому интересно, задачу надо свести к ограниченному числу фирм путем первого запроса. Затем сформировать с помощью php второй запрос где столбцы сводной таблицы задать выражением: "sum('кол-во товара'*(1-abs(sign('фирма'-'индекс фирмы')))) as exam1". 
пример взял отсюда - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming:MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: если можно сделайте ответ "Правильный" что бы завтра другим помогло

Answer (score 0):

Если число фирм постоянно, то можно воспользоваться case'ами или их аналогами, например: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78 .
Если число фирм произвольно, то вряд ли в текущей версии MySQL можно обойтись без процедурной логики.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. число фирм произвольно. буду биться дальше